# Is it possible to run an HVAC duct through a floor joist?

Tags: hvac

[image]i understand that the maximum size hole I can put through a 9" floor joist is 3". But if I add a 5" booster fan would it be possible to retain proper air flow and route this duct through the joist using a 5" to 3" reducer?

Comment: I'd look at splitting the duct into two 3" pipes as it passes through the joist. The added complexity and expense of a booster is to be avoided.

Comment: I'm confused about what I'm seeing up there. Why is one joist lower than the other? What are the boards at the left end?

Comment: Both joists are the same height, there are just boards scabbed onto the bottom of one.

Comment: Wouldn't you need more than two 3" pipes to keep the volume consistent?